# Creating a WordPress website on without uploading to the Internet

Tags: wordpress, web

I'm trying to make a simple website and I found out that wordpress is the easiest way to do.
I already have a web hosing and a domain.
Now my issue is that I want to make the website without being uploaded to internet
I wanna see it on my PC first and wait for sometime then release it when the time comes.
so i searched over the internet and all I found that a ways on how to get a web hosting and connecting it to a wordpress.
I don't need that, what I need to make a wordpress website keep it ready to publish when I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install WP on your own PC:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Installing_WordPress_on_your_own_Computer

After you finish, install WP on your server, upload your modified files, import your data (posts, etc.) in your database and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you install XAMPP or another server solution on your computer. That will simulate a server. That way you can just install Wordpress there to fiddle around with.

Then, when you really want to publish it you can just transfer the files to your actual webspace.

It really depends on what exactly you want to do with your Wordpress while it's still offline. Maybe I din't understand what you really want, could you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of tutorials on how to get a local wordpress.

```
You will need:
```

**For running a local PHP server**

- XAMPP (windows/mac)
- MAMP (Mac)

**Place this in your htdocs when you download the local server**

- A copy of wordpress

**Database management. This will come with the following local servers**

- phpmyadmin

http://www.inkthemes.com/12-simple-steps-to-install-wordpress-locally/01/

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-locally-on-mac-using-mamp/

https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-website-in-windows-with-xampp

Answer (score 0):

Very big question, but in short, if you want to develop the site offline, then you'll need to install some server software on your own PC and get wordpress running on it.

I recommend looking at [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) as this contains everything you'll need to get started.

After that you can install Wordpress, and get developing, then upload the files to your server via FTP when you're ready to launch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Wordpress on a server in order for it to run. You can develop the site and view it locally, but you will need to use something such as VirtualBox in order to set up a local web server. You can find out more about setting up a web server on VirtualBox [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DYkt3MeNwORQ&ei=di0fUtyaJ6Gt7Qa8g4HQBg&usg=AFQjCNGUI6hRZ1rUSbuYw6_Ldb8qYSlmGg&sig2=WWb2cPkRB1MIofJ-3K_m8w&bvm=bv.51495398,d.ZGU). I hope this helps.